# Evaluation of method System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList() calls into native method Interop+Kernel32.FindStringOrdinal() in QuickWatch

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have a list of posts that i get from DB like that:

```
 var iQueryablePost= from p in context.Posts
                     select new Post
                     {
                       Id=p.id,
                       Label=p.label
                     };
 var posts = new List<Post>();
 posts = await iQueryablePost.ToListAsync();
```

I wanna filter my **posts** after getting all from DB, if i add where to my iQueryable it works just fine but i need to get all post from DB.

That's what i did and the message I see in QuickWatch  :

```
posts = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.PdcIdSITiers) ? 
        posts.Where(c => c.Label.ToLower().Contains(query.label.ToLower())).ToList() : 
        posts;
```

**QuickWatch message:**

> Evaluation of method System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList() calls into native
>   method Interop+Kernel32.FindStringOrdinal().  Evaluation of native
>   methods in this context is not supported. 
>   System.Collections.Generic.List

[image]

The project is based in a **CQRS** design-pattern

Comment: Looks like you are running in some constrained execution context. What type of application is this? Btw, since you are working with `List`, the issue has nothing to do with EF Core.

Comment: Quick Google search for the exception message shows that this seems to be a VS debugging issue, so as I understand, It shouldn't happen at runtime.

Comment: @mjwills i saw this message in QuickWatch while debugging

Comment: @IvanStoev the issue happen in both modes runtime and debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probleme comes from a ***Label*** that is **Null** 
After deleting this row from my list the code work just fine.

Thanks for all your comments