# Using LINQ in Visual Studio QuickWatch with WCF objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, wcf, debugging

In my code, I create an array of objects. Those objects come from WCF.

```cs
var people = GetPeopleFromWCF().ToArray();
```

I set the breakpoint after array assigning, run the debugger, the code is paused in the proper breakpoint. I go to the QuickWatch window and can discover the array objects properties. When I use some LINQ methods in the QuickWatch window like

`people.Select(x => x.DateOfBirth), results`

or `people.Select(x => x.DateOfBirth).ToList()`

or `people.Select(x => x.DateOfBirth).ToArray()`

I got the next error:

> Evaluation of method
> System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1[System.DateTime].get_Items()
> calls into native method
> Microsoft.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.QueryPerformanceCounter(long&).
> Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.

When in the QuickWatch window I type `people.First().DateOfBirth` - I got the proper result.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.7.3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 16.7.3 is the current version of VS 2019.

Comment: How about if you try with `ToList()` like `people.Select(x => x.DateOfBirth).ToList()`?

Comment: Selim Yildiz, same result.

Comment: @MaciejLos, I install the newest 16.7.3 version and got the same result.

Comment: Try `x.DateOfBirth.ToString()` to see if that works.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 has solved this problem. According to my test, the QuickWatch window monitors the LINQ method perfectly. Could you please provide detailed code to ask for more help?

Comment: @Arya, I try to reproduce this with a small console app, but I can't. It appears only in my big production web-application. Probably there is a dependency that I don't see.

Comment: I suggest you could do it with Immediate Window, and see if there are different results.

Comment: @Arya, with Immediate Window - same result

Comment: I suspect the error appears because the collection objects come from WCF.

Comment: it looks like an issue with how VS treats [`DebuggerBrowsableAttribute`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2723) on collection of your specific objects (WCF seems to contribute to the issue). I know, [a somewhat similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/377921/evaluation-of-native-methods-in-this-context-is-no.html) has been fixed before, so you might have more luck reporting this to VS dev team

Comment: your question, "What am I doing wrong?", and intention isn't clear.  what are you attempting to do? suppress the error?  load native debug symbols? what are you inhibited in doing or want an answer on?... also, Provide your Debug > Option settings... and Project > Debug settings.  additionally, is this x86 or x64? have you tried both?

Comment: Could you please try the steps given on "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-evaluating-the-function-function-timed-out-and-needed-to-be-aborted-in-an-unsafe-way?view=vs-2019" ?

Comment: The same question was asked last (year sep 19 2019). Read the full discussion here. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1be7619d-b463-4029-ad23-901dc71f9391/evaluation-of-method?forum=vsdebug . If you haven't solved you are more likely required to report this issue on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com.

Comment: The same question was asked last (year sep 19 2019). Read the full discussion here. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1be7619d-b463-4029-ad23-901dc71f9391/evaluation-of-method?forum=vsdebug . If you haven't solved you are more likely required to report this issue on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com.

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to tell what `people` actually is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197842/evaluation-of-method-system-linq-enumerable-tolist-calls-into-native-method-in

Comment: The problem comes from a Label that is Null After deleting this row from my list the code work just fine.

Thanks for all your comments said Omar AMEZOUG edited by me

Comment: in short are you hundred percent sure the field DateOfBirth does exist in people?  and DateOfBirth is not null in every record of your table

Comment: people.Select(x =>new {"BirthDate" = x.DateOfBirth == null?"":x.DateOfBirth.ToString()}).ToList()

Comment: @Gert Arnold sorry mistake deleted the link